# GoogleSheets UPDATE only one cell

Tags: objective-c, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to UPDATE a cell I have in Google Sheets.

```
- (void)listMajors {
    NSLog(@"Getting sheet data...");
    NSString *spreadsheetId = @"MY_ID";


    GTLRSheets_ValueRange *data = [GTLRSheets_ValueRange valueForKey:@"TEST"];



    GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate *update = [GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate queryWithObject:data spreadsheetId:spreadsheetId range:superRange];

 //   GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet *query =
   // [GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesGet queryWithSpreadsheetId:spreadsheetId
     //                                                       range:superRange];

    self.service.APIKey = @"MY_API_KEY";



    [self.service executeQuery:update
                      delegate:self
             didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}
```

This is my attempt. My desired goal is to update the certain cell (one cell) at one location. Please help :)

Comment: And what is your code currently doing? What's issue?

Comment: It just isn't updating my cell... do you want the exact debug output? I believe it means the JSON is off - in essence, what I need is to know how create the right GTLRSheets_ValueRange *data